# Change color of legend to match line plot matplotlib pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, colors, legend, line-plot

Update, edited code to mcve version problem is in line 17.

I am trying to plot a multiple line chart from a .csv file. I have managed to change the default colors in the plot to tableau20 color scheme. When I generate a legend the colors in the legend remain the default colors. If I try to add a color command to the legend code section I get errors. TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'. Is there a way to match the legend colors to the colors in the main chart body?

Here is the code and a few lines of the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('cch30.csv')
tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),    
             (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150)]
for i in range(len(tableau20)):    
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]    
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)
ax = df.plot(kind='line', x=df.columns[0],y=df.columns[1:8])
species= ['A. bellonorium', 'A. fuscolingua', 'A. mucronata', 'A. depressa', 'A. novazelandia', 'A. spp', 'A. australis']
for rank, column in enumerate(species):        
    plt.plot(df.Position.values,    
            df[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,    
            lw=1, color=tableau20[rank])
    lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    #problem in the next line when i try to tell it to use tableau20 by adding color=tableau20[rank]after fontsize
    ax.legend(lines[0:8], labels[0:8], loc='best', fontsize=8, color=tableau20[rank])
plt.show()
```

---

```
Position,A. bellonorium,A. fuscolingua,A. mucronata,A. depressa,A. novazelandia,A. spp,A. australis
1,17,9,33,22,15,20,78
2,17,9,33,21,14,22,77
3,17,9,34,20,14,23,78
4,17,9,35,21,12,23,79
5,17,9,34,22,12,24,75
6,17,9,34,22,13,24,75
7,17,9,34,22,13,24,74
8,17,9,34,22,15,24,76
9,16,9,36,20,14,24,76
10,16,9,36,20,15,26,75
11,16,9,37,20,15,27,74
12,16,9,36,21,15,26,74
13,16,9,34,21,15,27,75
14,16,9,34,23,15,27,75
15,16,9,34,24,16,26,75
16,16,9,34,24,16,28,76
17,16,9,33,24,16,28,77
18,15,9,34,24,14,28,77
19,15,9,32,25,14,28,77
20,15,9,32,25,13,28,77
21,15,9,31,25,13,29,79
22,15,9,31,25,13,29,79
23,15,9,32,25,13,29,78
24,15,9,31,25,12,29,79
25,15,9,30,25,12,29,78
26,15,9,30,25,12,28,79
27,15,9,29,24,13,30,80
28,15,9,30,24,13,30,80
29,14,9,29,23,11,30,77
```

Comment: Hi, it may be worthwhile to put together a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example. Ideally one could copy the code you wrote and reproduce the error you are getting. There is a lot of code in your example that does not relate to the question. I am unable to reproduce your error, however I am also unable to run the code you presented because I don't have the csv you are using.

Comment: Done, I think. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to run your exact code because I do not have access to the csv that you are using so I'm just guessing as to what your dataframe looks like. But you should be able to adapt the following code to what you need. I tried to make the code as minimum as possible as this will be easier to troubleshoot if you run into issues

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [.5, 1, 2]], columns=['A. bellonorium', 'A. fuscolingua', 'A. mucronata'])

tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (255, 152, 150), (255, 127, 14)]
tableau20 = [(r/255, g/255, b/255) for r, g, b in tableau20]

f, ax = plt.subplots()

for rank, column in enumerate(df.columns):        
    ax.plot(df.index, df[column], color=tableau20[rank], label=column)

ax.legend(loc='best')
```

the `legend` method doesn't have a color parameter which is why you were getting the error, I'm not sure why you weren't getting the correct colors in the labels, however you don't need to explicitly state what the colors are, as those are contained in the axes object. You may also want to define the labels in the plotting method so that they show up in the legend. Good luck[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR9l9.png)

Comment: Thanks. Took some lines of yours and mixed it in with mine and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This code got the result I wanted at this stage. Thanks to all those who helped

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('coveragechart.csv')
tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),    
             (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150)]
for i in range(len(tableau20)):    
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]    
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
for rank, column in enumerate(df.columns[1:8]):        
    ax.plot(df.index, df[column], color=tableau20[rank], label=column)
    plt.ylabel('Coverage')
    plt.xlabel('Position')
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)
plt.savefig('cov.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```